# pl/pgSQL function merge in Postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, function, merge

[image: here's a picture in context]
with error message

No, no image link.  Wow, you need to be a real programmer to figure this out.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/ReCF1f7kuxvpm2R03

I must be doing something epically stupid.  It says my table is an unknown variable, but the table is right there. Is it going into the wrong database or something?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION s_ar_update()
returns void AS $$
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO s_ar_hist h USING s_ar_stage s ON s.cocd = h.cocd and s.documentno = h.documentno and s.itm = hist.itm
    WHEN MATCHED THEN DO NOTHING
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (s.cocd, s.account, s.invoice_ref, s.documentno, s.type, s.reference, s.doc_date, s.payt, s.net_due_dt, s.amount_in_dc, s.curr, s.amt_in_loc_cur,s.lcur,s.amt,s.cur,s.pstng_date,s.text,s.pk, s.doucment_header_text,s.rcd,s.clrng_doc,s.clearing,s.itm.s.item,s.year_month,s.accty,s.cc,s.period,s.pmnt_date,.s.eff_ex_rate,s.gl_amount,s.gl)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN DELETE;

    insert s_ar_collisions
    select * from s_ar_stage

END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also I can't get the code to format so nicely.  IT looks fine in this text editor. I guess that's another SO question

Comment: postgres does not have MERGE SQL directive I belive

Comment: Oh my god, I just saw this 'This was never integrated into PostgreSQL, and requires significant work to be production quality' on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples.  Is this still true?

Comment: And now my code is formatted nicely.  How did that happen?  Does it just take some time for the engine to render?

Comment: I showed example in my asnwer. it parses to the INTO and never hits what is before

Answer (score 0):

```
t=# do
$$
begin
  anything here into vaname from a;
end;
$$;
ERROR:  "vaname" is not a known variable
LINE 4:   anything here into vaname from a;
                             ^
Time: 0.420 ms`enter code here`
```

why? because it is parsed from the end I suppose. And never gets to the `anything here` statement - so you don't see `MERGE` exception. Postgres [does not have MERGE command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html). So it gets `INTO` and thinks you want to assign a value to variable - not insert into table. and thus you see this exception